# Why does ArcMap not see *.jpeg files?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, jpg

I want to georeference a *.jpeg object but I cannot even add the data to ArcMap which does not seem to see the files?

Comment: Can you view them in ArcCatalog?

Comment: ArcGIS is very picky about file extensions...

Answer (score 11):

In the **[Help for Supported raster dataset file formats](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009t0000000q000000)** it says:

> ArcCatalog only recognizes the .jpg file extension by default. To add
>   .jpeg or .jpe files to ArcMap without renaming them, add those file
>   extensions to ArcCatalog or drag those files from Windows Explorer
>   into your map.

Answer (score 7):

You can make ArcCatalog recognize .jpeg files by adding it as a File Type in ArcCatalog options.

Inside ArcCatalog:

- From the main menu choose:  `Customize`
- Select `ArcCatalog Options`
- Under the `File Types` tab choose `New Type...`
- Enter "jpeg" and "JPEG Image"

.jpeg images will now display in ArcCatalog.

UPDATE: For ArcMap, you have to separately add .jpeg as a Raster File Format.

Inside ArcMap:

- From the main menu choose `Customize`
- Select `ArcMap Options`
- Under the `Raster` tab choose the `Raster Dataset` tab and click the `File Formats...` button.
- Scroll to the record for "JPEG" under the Rater Formats list and double-click to edit
- Change this record so the File Extensions section contains: `*.jpg;*.jpeg`

After making this change, I had to restart ArcMap to see the file in the Add Data dialog.  There may be a way to refresh these views without restarting.